# Add a download functionality in django change view

Tags: javascript, html, django

I already added a button alongside the save buttons for my django change view:

```
{% extends 'admin/change_form.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block submit_buttons_bottom %}
    <div class="submit-row">
        <input type="submit" value="Download" id="download_profile" name="_continue">
        <input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Save' %}" class="default" name="_save">
        <input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Save and add another' %}" name="_addanother">
        <input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Save and continue editing' %}" name="_continue">
<!-- inmport script -->
<script src="{% static '/js/downloadData.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static '/js/collapsibleSection.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static '/js/investmentAdminScript.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

[image]

and I already started adding the script to retrieve individual data per row to download them.

```
'use strict';

window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    const downloadButton = document.querySelector('#download_profile');

    downloadButton.addEventListener('click', e => {
        if (!confirm('Data will be saved before downloading. Are you sure you want to continue?')) {
            e.preventDefault();
            return;
        }
        // get module
        const fieldsets = document.querySelectorAll('fieldset');

        fieldsets.forEach(thisFieldset => {
            const dataRows = thisFieldset.querySelectorAll('.form-row');
            dataRows.forEach(dataRow => {
                // retrieve each input field and add a download to .xlsx function
            });
        });
    });
});
```

However, it gets complicated very fast. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Found a single JS file that allows you to format .xlsx files and start a download with one function

https://github.com/egeriis/zipcelx

Since you're using django, download the "standalone.js" file and add it to your static files. Reference it in your template in a script tag. Now you'll have access to the "zipcelx()" function

Here's a "getting started" example I made

```
const config = {
    filename: "practice-file",
    sheet: {
        data: [
            // Row 1
            [
                {value: "row1 value1",type:"string"},
                {value: "1000",type: 'number'}
            ],

            // Row 2
            [
                {value: "row2 value1", type: 'string'},
                {value: "row2 value2", type: "string"}
            ]
        ]
    }
}


// call zipcelx to immediately start the download in client's browser
zipcelx(config)
```

[Example of the File Generated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ricKI.png)

Don't know how large your data sets are, might get tedious with having to format your data in such a way. Some helper functions should do the trick if that became a problem.

Hope this helped!